# vue3 v-model calculation works after refreshing web browser [vue 3 + axios]

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, vuejs3

I'm studying CRUD with Laravel 9 + Vue 3 + axios.
I'm working on number calculation using v-model.
This code working. but. I have a problem.

I successed 'num1' + 'num2' calculation and I can get esult which is 'sum1' and
I successed saved 'sum1' to datababase also.

When I open this number input page then type num1 and num2
sum1 doesn't show up. this is auto calculation part.

So I tried refresh web broswer. then this work.
Could some one teach me what is causing please?

**[Create.vue]**

```
<input type="number" name="num1" id="num1" v-model="form.num1">
{{ form.num1.toLocaleString() }}                       

<input type="number" name="num2" id="num2" v-model="form.num2">
{{ form.num2.toLocaleString() }}

{{ form.num1 + form.num2 }}
<input type="number" name="sum1" id="sum1" class=""　v-model="form.sum1" >
                   
                   

<script setup>
import { computed, reactive } from "vue";
import useCompanies from "@/composables/companies";

const form = reactive({
    'num1': '',
    'num2': '', 
    'sum1': '', 
    })
    const sum1 = computed(() => {
    return form.sum1 = form.num1 + form.num2
})

const { errors, storeCompany } = useCompanies()
const saveCompany = async () => {
    await storeCompany({ ...form });
}
```

**[UPDATE:Solved my problem]**

```
const num1 = ref(0);
const num2 = ref(0);

const sum1 = computed(() => num1.value + num2.value);

const form = reactive({    
    'sum1': sum1, 
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your computed is setting sum1 by "side effect", as if it were a function, which it isn't, and that shouldn't be, and as you're finding, doesn't work. Instead, I would recommend removing `sum1` from the form, and instead, just using the `sum1` computed property, either that, or use a watcher.

As per the [Vue.js documentation on "best practices" with computed properties"](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html#best-practices):

> **Getters should be side-effect free​**
> It is important to remember that computed getter functions should only perform pure computation and be free of side effects. For example, don't make async requests or mutate the DOM inside a computed getter! Think of a computed property as declaratively describing how to derive a value based on other values - its only responsibility should be computing and returning that value. Later in the guide we will discuss how we can perform side effects in reaction to state changes with watchers.

Comment: Thank you for answering me. I see. I learned a lot thank you! And actually I had trying to remove 'sum1' from 'from' . but i did so then I couldn't send 'sum1' result data to database. Could you please teach me right code please?

Comment: Thank you very much for show me the path to solve problem.

Comment: Dear @Hovercraft Full Of Eels  I just solved problem. I update code. Thank you very much!